# find minimum value in a while loop of array returned from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a query like:

```
 select * from posts p where p.post like '%cadillac%' ORDER BY p.upvotes DESC,
 p.unix_timestamp DESC LIMIT 20
```

Now, while looping through the array, i need to find the minimum `unix_timestamp` value. Something like:

```
 $counter = 0;
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

 // what do i do here to find the minimum timestamp value 

 $counter = $counter + 1;
 }
```

Please advise.

Comment: This sounds quite simply, maybe I didn't get the question right... Store unix_timestamp value in a variable and check if the current row's value is smaller, if yes then save that value in the variable.

Comment: why the down vote if i may ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $counter = 0;
 $min_timestamp = 0;
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

     //check if min hasn't been set OR if the current timestamp is less than the min
     if(!$min_timestamp || ($row['unix_timestamp'] < $min_timestamp)) {
         //store this timestamp as the current min
         $min_timestamp = $row['unix_timestamp'];
     } 

     //$counter = $counter + 1;
 }
 //once we reach here, min_timestamp will hold the minimum timestamp found
```

Comment: how will this return the minimum value as you're testing all values against 0 ?

Comment: remove `$min_timestamp = 0;` and add `if(!isset($min_timestamp)) $min_timestamp=$row['unix_timestamp'];` inside the loop OR prefetch the first row

Comment: @coder101 I'm not sure I understand your question: it will get inside if() on the first pass and assign the first row unix_ts to the $min_timestamp variable.

Comment: @Waygood the first row might have the highest timestamp value as the rows are in descending order of upvotes and being most recent. So i wouldn't know for sure if the first row's timestamp would be the minimum one

Comment: @coder101, now  there are comments added to the code, just read them

Comment: `prefetch the first row` was to initialise the timestamp (instead of min_timestamp=0), the loop will take care of the rest

Comment: i hope you incorporated the fact that the first row might not necessarily be the one with the lowest value because of the order clauses

Comment: P.S. the timestamp values are like `1360683849`

Comment: we don't care whether it is minimum or maximum. We just save the first row value as "current minimum" on the first pass. And on every subsequent pass we compare current row value to the "current minimum"

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment about timestamp format, this is extremely useful info for me!

Comment: Pardon me if i am being stupid, but what you just said, will that give me the correct min timestamp value?

Comment: well, I think so :) Just try it on your code and report any issues here

Comment: it works fine.. All you good guys out there, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
$counter = 0;
$min_value;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $min_value = is_null($min_value) || $min_value > $row['unix_timestamp'] ? $row['unix_timestamp'] :$min_value  ;

  $counter = $counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: This will not work. $min_value will always be null here, since you are setting $min_value = $min_value every time. The || will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks, man. i ended up using Alexeys answer, though, just knowing another approach is good too

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your SQL

```
select MIN(unix_timestamp) from posts p where p.post like '%cadillac%'
```

Comment: This isn't what he's asking for, as it'll affect the amount of rows that come back.

Comment: i want all other field values too. so may be like, `select MIN(unix_timestamp), p.* from posts p where p.post like '%cadillac%' ORDER BY p.upvotes DESC,
 p.unix_timestamp DESC LIMIT 20`. is this correct?

Comment: @JimmySawczuk think this is what he is asking.

Comment: @75inchpianist try running that query; it'll only return one row. The query he has above might return way more than one. It's because `MIN` works in the aggregate, which isn't what you want (at least not yet).

Comment: @JimmySawczuk he only wants the row with the minimum unix timestamp it sounds like.

Comment: no no, thats not what i want. i want all the rows and a way to figure out the minimum timestamp returned so that i can run another query to fetch further records

Comment: what about `SELECT *, MIN(unix_timestamp) FROM (select * from posts p where p.post like '%cadillac%' ORDER BY p.upvotes DESC, p.unix_timestamp DESC LIMIT 20) as tempy` you'll get an extra column showing the minimum of that set

Comment: @Waygood this is just one of the queries, i have a lot of other queries with further sub queries requiring the same operation

Comment: I think this might cause problems since the two selectors have different # of columns

Comment: @75inchpianist if your referring to mine, then no it wont cause a problem. coder101 Go for Alexys answer if thats what you require

Comment: @Waygood I was not referring to you, but yours does repeat the min in the result rows :/ Still I like this better than having php handle cycling through comparing the date.

Comment: i have a problem understanding @Alexys' answer. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I submitted an edit with comments in code, awaiting peer review

Comment: sorry @Justin_Bicknell is better